# getExternalFilesDir return different paths in different devices

Tags: android

In most devices the call `context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` returns the Path `Android/data/com.XXXX.YYY/files/Download`. But on a Samsung GT-P1010 running Android 2.2.1 with the same APK this call returns `external_sd/Android/data/com.XXXX.YYY/files/Download`. I need the same path in all the devices. How can I obtain it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the purpose of this method. The path may differ between devices. To stay compatible with all of these you should use the path provided by the method.

If you want to keep the same path, hardcode it into a string. But expect things to break in this case.
**Not recommended**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, and it should be so that you don't hardcode your paths. That prevents you from accessing paths that doesn't exist.